# Grouping values by month and by quarter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have data like

MyTable

```
person   datetimeField   datavalue1
 a        20110104        3
 a2       20110105        2 
 b        20110302        5
 c        20110403        6
 d        20110605        2
```

The final result should look like:  (Order isn't important)

```
 DatePart    SumDatavalue1
 January      5
 March        5
 April        6
 June         2
 Quarter1     10
 Quarter2     8
```

The only way I can think of is to use two separate select statements with GROUP BYs and then doing a UNION ALL. Is there a more efficient way?

Edit: I should say that there may be another column, datavalue2, that would need to be averaged, instead of summed. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.  This is what `grouping sets` where designed for.  Here is an example of SQL that does what you want:

```
select (case when datename(mm, dt) is null
             then qtr
             else datename(mm, dt)
        end), count(*), sum(val)
from (select t.*,
             'Quarter'+cast(datepart(qq, dt) as varchar(255)) as qtr
      from temp t
     ) t
group by grouping sets((datename(mm, dt)),
                       (qtr))
order by (case when qtr is null then 0 else 1 end),
         min(dt)
```

The SQLFiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3aded/29).

In response to your comment, `grouping sets` are a generalization of `rollup` (and `cube`).  With `grouping sets` you can add the total like this:

```
select (case when datename(mm, dt) is null and qtr is null
             then 'Total'
             when datename(mm, dt) is null
             then qtr
             else datename(mm, dt)
        end), count(*), sum(val)
from (select t.*,
             'Quarter'+cast(datepart(qq, dt) as varchar(255)) as qtr
      from temp t
     ) t
group by grouping sets((datename(mm, dt)),
                       (qtr),
                       ())
order by (case when qtr is null and datename(mm, dt) is null then 2
               when datename(mm, dt) is null then 1
               else 0
          end),
         min(dt)
```

The major complication is printing out the right value in the first column and getting the ordering right.

Comment: Interesting that there's two ways to do this - using rollup (Talasila's answer) and grouping sets. Which is the most appropriate in this case? Also, if I needed to add a Grand total to this, how would I do it?

Comment: Disregard the second question. I added an empty grouping set '()'. I'm assuming using Grouping Sets has more flexibility?
I'll just read this page here. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510427(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use ROLLUP for SubTotals ... its efficient because it goes through the detailed data only once unlike 2 separate GroupBys

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN [DATEPART] IS NULL THEN 'Quarter' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),QQ)
             ELSE [DATEPART] END [DatePart], [SumDataValue1] 
 FROM  (
         SELECT DATENAME(mm, dateTimefield ) [DATEPART],DATENAME(qq, dateTimefield ) [QQ] , SUM(datavalue1) [SumDataValue1] 
         FROM MyTable
         GROUP BY DATENAME(qq, dateTimefield ), DATENAME(mm, dateTimefield ) WITH ROLLUP )A
 WHERE ( [DATEPART] IS NOT NULL OR QQ IS NOT NULL )
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for ..

Comment: Thanks, this works! Made a small change to also include a grand total at the bottom. I'll have to read more about Rollup and Grouping Sets